# How to get DynamoDB monitoring metrics to InfluxDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, influxdb, grafana, amazon-cloudwatch

I am building a monitoring pipeline, has any one tried to get the DynamoDB monitoring metrics into InfluxDB without having custom code running in EC2/Lambda. Are there any plugins that might handle this?

If you have some good idea or can suggest a plugin please share with me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can Pull DynamoDB Matrics from AWS to InfluxDB using 
[Telegraf](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf) Library.

> Telegraf is an agent written in Go for collecting, processing,
>   aggregating, and writing metrics.

**Note :** You don't need to Have Custom Code Running in EC2/Lambda for the same.

As Per [Issue Raised for : influxdata/telegraf](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/issues/1907#issuecomment-256504506)

> Here are the metrics that do end up in InfluxDB:
>
> ```
> cloudwatch_aws_efs
> cloudwatch_aws_elastic_beanstalk
> cloudwatch_aws_elb
> cloudwatch_aws_lambda
> cloudwatch_aws_rds
> ```
>
> Config:
>
> ```
> [[inputs.cloudwatch]]
>   role_arn = 'arn:aws:iam::MYACCOUNT:role/MYROLE'
>   region = 'us-east-1'
>   period = '1m'
>   delay = '3m'
>   interval = '3m'
>   namespace = 'AWS/ApplicationELB'
>   [inputs.cloudwatch.tags]
>     aws_account = 'MYACCOUNT'
>
> [[inputs.cloudwatch]]
>   role_arn = 'arn:aws:iam::MYACCOUNT:role/MYROLE'
>   region = 'us-east-1'
>   period = '1m'
>   delay = '3m'
>   interval = '3m'
>   namespace = 'AWS/AutoScaling'
>   [inputs.cloudwatch.tags]
>     aws_account = 'MYACCOUNT'
>
> [[inputs.cloudwatch]]
>   role_arn = 'arn:aws:iam::MYACCOUNT:role/MYROLE'
>   region = 'us-east-1'
>   period = '1m'
>   delay = '3m'
>   interval = '3m'
>   namespace = 'AWS/DynamoDB'
>   [inputs.cloudwatch.tags]
>     aws_account = 'MYACCOUNT'
>
> [[inputs.cloudwatch]]
>   role_arn = 'arn:aws:iam::MYACCOUNT:role/MYROLE'
>   region = 'us-east-1'
>   period = '1m'
>   delay = '3m'
>   interval = '3m'
>   namespace = 'AWS/EC2'
>   [[inputs.cloudwatch.metrics]]
>     names = [ 'CPUCreditBalance', 'CPUCreditUsage', 'StatusCheckFailed', 'StatusCheckFailed_Instance',
> ```
>
> 'StatusCheckFailed_System' ]
>         [inputs.cloudwatch.tags]
>           aws_account = 'MYACCOUNT'
>
> ```
> [[inputs.cloudwatch]]
>   role_arn = 'arn:aws:iam::MYACCOUNT:role/MYROLE'
>   region = 'us-east-1'
>   period = '1m'
>   delay = '3m'
>   interval = '3m'
>   namespace = 'AWS/ElasticBeanstalk'
>   [inputs.cloudwatch.tags]
>     aws_account = 'MYACCOUNT'
>
> [[inputs.cloudwatch]]
>   role_arn = 'arn:aws:iam::MYACCOUNT:role/MYROLE'
>   region = 'us-east-1'
>   period = '1m'
>   delay = '3m'
>   interval = '3m'
>   namespace = 'AWS/EFS'
>   [inputs.cloudwatch.tags]
>     aws_account = 'MYACCOUNT'
>
> [[inputs.cloudwatch]]
>   role_arn = 'arn:aws:iam::MYACCOUNT:role/MYROLE'
>   region = 'us-east-1'
>   period = '1m'
>   delay = '3m'
>   interval = '3m'
>   namespace = 'AWS/ELB'
>   [inputs.cloudwatch.tags]
>     aws_account = 'MYACCOUNT'
>
> [[inputs.cloudwatch]]
>   role_arn = 'arn:aws:iam::MYACCOUNT:role/MYROLE'
>   region = 'us-east-1'
>   period = '1m'
>   delay = '3m'
>   interval = '3m'
>   namespace = 'AWS/ElasticMapReduce'
>   [inputs.cloudwatch.tags]
>     aws_account = 'MYACCOUNT'
>
> [[inputs.cloudwatch]]
>   role_arn = 'arn:aws:iam::MYACCOUNT:role/MYROLE'
>   region = 'us-east-1'
>   period = '1m'
>   delay = '3m'
>   interval = '3m'
>   namespace = 'AWS/Kinesis'
>   [inputs.cloudwatch.tags]
>     aws_account = 'MYACCOUNT'
>
> [[inputs.cloudwatch]]
>   role_arn = 'arn:aws:iam::MYACCOUNT:role/MYROLE'
>   region = 'us-east-1'
>   period = '1m'
>   delay = '3m'
>   interval = '3m'
>   namespace = 'AWS/Lambda'
>   [inputs.cloudwatch.tags]
>     aws_account = 'MYACCOUNT'
>
> [[inputs.cloudwatch]]
>   role_arn = 'arn:aws:iam::MYACCOUNT:role/MYROLE'
>   region = 'us-east-1'
>   period = '1m'
>   delay = '3m'
>   interval = '3m'
>   namespace = 'AWS/Redshift'
>   [inputs.cloudwatch.tags]
>     aws_account = 'MYACCOUNT'
>
> [[inputs.cloudwatch]]
>   role_arn = 'arn:aws:iam::MYACCOUNT:role/MYROLE'
>   region = 'us-east-1'
>   period = '1m'
>   delay = '3m'
>   interval = '3m'
>   namespace = 'AWS/RDS'
>   [inputs.cloudwatch.tags]
>     aws_account = 'MYACCOUNT'
>
> [[inputs.cloudwatch]]
>   role_arn = 'arn:aws:iam::MYACCOUNT:role/MYROLE'
>   region = 'us-east-1'
>   period = '1m'
>   delay = '3m'
>   interval = '3m'
>   namespace = 'AWS/SNS'
>   [inputs.cloudwatch.tags]
>     aws_account = 'MYACCOUNT'
>
> [[inputs.cloudwatch]]
>   role_arn = 'arn:aws:iam::MYACCOUNT:role/MYROLE'
>   region = 'us-east-1'
>   period = '1m'
>   delay = '3m'
>   interval = '3m'
>   namespace = 'AWS/SQS'
>   [inputs.cloudwatch.tags]
>     aws_account = 'MYACCOUNT'
>
> [[inputs.cloudwatch]]
>   role_arn = 'arn:aws:iam::MYACCOUNT:role/MYROLE'
>   region = 'us-east-1'
>   period = '1m'
>   delay = '60m'
>   interval = '60m'
>   namespace = 'AWS/S3'
>   [inputs.cloudwatch.tags]
>     aws_account = 'MYACCOUNT'
> ```

Also, As Per https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/issues/1907#issuecomment-258270588

> **AutoScaling metrics are not enabled by default in AWS accounts.**
>
> Have you enabled them for some ASGs?
>
> Follow :
>   http://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/latest/userguide/as-instance-monitoring.html#as-enable-group-metrics
>
> **If you have not enabled them for any ASG, then cloudwatch returns an empty list of metrics available for the AWS/AutoScaling namespace.**

Comment: @HusainKhambaty, what do you think ? It's Established & already implemented ;)

Comment: @lokesh-raj-urs, Did this answer help you solve your question ?

Comment: will have to give it a shot then :)